# 301 redirect through .htaccess moving url parts

Tags: .htaccess

i need help setting up 301 redirect something like 
the URL `domain.com/f446623/welcome-new-guest/` need to be redirected to `domain.com/folder/welcome-new-guest.446623/`
basically f will become folder and numbers which are post IDs moved at end after the title along with dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/f([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /folder/$2.$1
```